# How to get automatically every 5 mins once push notification from pushbots?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, pushbots

Am create cordova app in that am using pushbot plugin. now i send any push message from pushbot means that message as come to my phone. but i need How to get 5mins once push notification from pushbots automatically?

Simply i want every 5mins once push notification from pushbots thats it.

am using cordova version 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');

```
    window.plugins.PushbotsPlugin.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", {"android":{"sender_id":"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}});
    // Only with First time registration
    window.plugins.PushbotsPlugin.on("registered", function(token){
    });

    //Get user registrationId/token and userId on PushBots, with evey launch of the app even launching with notification
    window.plugins.PushbotsPlugin.on("user:ids", function(data){
        console.log("user:ids" + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

},
```

Comment: What you mean by `i want every 5mins once push notification from pushbots thats it`?

Comment: i want same push message in every 5 or 15 minuets once reputedly get push message to my phone with using pushbots.